# Re sizing absolute positioned divs with dynamic left values jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wrote up a function that works ok, but when I extend it to add multiple layers I can tell my math is all off. I am essentially trying to resize absolute divs by changing thier width, left, top values (for this question I'm more focused on understanding the math and working with `$(window).width()`, adjusting the left values, and possibly the width if you want to get into more depth). Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8rDt/5/) to [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V8rDt/5/) what I am talking about a little better.

Again this functionality to me is primary based on proper mathematics, which is why I am failing because I know the math is off, and I am not sure how to take the elements I am working with and leverage the window width to scale it.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8rDt/5/) should explain it all, but let me give you some quick details.

**Details:** *A user can add as many layers as he/she would like using jQuery's `.draggable()` the layer is dragged to the desired position, then saved to the DB then that position and the contents are used on the front end.*

What I am trying to do is make this responsive, css doesnt work well because the positions are random/dynamic.

**HTML example:**

```
  <div class="jsfiddle-container">
    <div class="example">

      // You can see the positions are in no particular order
      <div class="d1" data-orig="191px" style="position: absolute; left: 191px;"><span></span>Stewie Griffen</div>
      <div class="d2" data-orig="10px" style="position: absolute; left: 10px;"><span></span>Brian Griffen</div>
      <div class="d3" data-orig="419px" style="position: absolute; left: 419px;"><span></span>Peter Griffen</div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery snippet:** *More in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8rDt/5/)*

```
  obj.each(function () {
        var leftData = $(this).data('orig');
        var left = parseInt(leftData);
        $(this).css({

              'left': w_d - left,
              'width': w_d,

  });
```

**Closing:** The framework I feel is pretty much all set up, it's just about getting the math down, and tying the `$(window).width()` with the left value as the screen is scrolling and also setting the width up properly.

*Some help would be fantastic and save me a lot of headache, I am also excited to hear everyone's input. Also if you want more details please ask, I re wrote some code to suit the fiddle its not perfect, but I want to show you what I am talking about and perhaps give you something to play with.*

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is, when the container is < 800px width, all divs change width and left in order to fill the top perfectly, then why not use the percent based on the width as 100% and the number of elements as the splitter.

e.g. If the width was 600px and you had 3 divs, then 600px would be 100%, you'd have 3 elements, so 33% each = 600/3 = 200px each. Then starting from 0, set your lefts to increment by this amount.

```
var itemWidth = 0;
var numOfItems = $(obj).length;
var containerWidth = $(".jsfiddle-container").css.width;

if (containerWidth <= 800)
{
    itemWidth = containerWidth / numOfItems;
    var count = 0;

    obj.each(function () {
        $(this).css({
          'left': (itemWidth * count) + 'px',
          'width': itemWidth + 'px',

        });
        count++;
    });
}
else
{
    // Set static width
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the really late reply, I fell asleep after asking this. Yeah I actually thought about something like this, but I wasn't sure how to get the number of items, I was going to ask that question, now I see it's as simple as using `.length()` this seems pretty soild I made some modifications though, Instead of `.jsfiddle-container` width I needed the `$(window).width()` so I update my fiddle based on your codes logic.. http://jsfiddle.net/V8rDt/6/ this really helps me out a lot thanks. Although I feel I might need to tweak it in the live version, this sets me up nicely. THANKS!

Comment: Actually I already caught a kink, when under 800px brian griffen is all the way to the left, but since its the second in order under 800px it get reorganized to take its position in the markup. When it should stay left even though in the markup its in the middle. NEW http://jsfiddle.net/V8rDt/7/